# What hash encryption algorithm does web3 use? ethereumjs-util Sha3 returns different result

Tags: javascript, hash, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to properly sign an authentication method through web3's signPersonalMessage function. However, eth-sig-util's package which correctly authenticates does not produce the same hash with the same data as both SHA3-256 and Keccak-256.

For example, if i try to hash:
`0x664f5f32784d335a69596e4f416c636373496859377054744f704c6e54666a314c70314a4f364d565f4638`

My result with Keccak256:
`5dc2751b78fdb82a0986ad2a8e6cc774458d7a096e8eafd3ab6937146b7d2eec`

My result with SHA3-256:
`6fa399a29899ebab112d562526b9b735f0cf7ce4bdc5a96edfcc48572b8d3e7b`

My result with the library's Sha3 function:
`40de9eb1ead6a6299af30cdf51eca39d44be214ce7431c93ff546cf5fb1ef0fb`

This is the only issue I can think of, I also often encountered an 'Incorrect v length' or 'invalid signature length' error before when I tried to sign and authenticate with Keccak.

Comment: What version of the library are you using?  [`ethereumjs-util` removed `sha3` in 6.0.0.](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/46ed31db75aacaa3c124ee251229d09ffe0534c8/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: I was using v5.2.0, guess I'll have to make sure it still auths in 6.0.0. Thank you!

Comment: I'm actually using its Keccak function, and even in version 6.1.0 it's still returning different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using web3.js 0.20.x and failing to pass the `encoding` parameter. That will treat the input as a string, which probably isn't what you want:

```
web3.sha3('0x664f5f32784d335a69596e4f416c636373496859377054744f704c6e54666a314c70314a4f364d565f4638', { encoding: 'hex' })
"0x40de9eb1ead6a6299af30cdf51eca39d44be214ce7431c93ff546cf5fb1ef0fb"
```

Answer (score 0):

web3 has 2 methods that use:

```
web3.utils.sha3 
web3.utils.soliditySha3
```

Even though, names include "Sha3", actually they implement `keccak256`. the difference is in packing of data, soliditySha3 using tight packing.

[tightly packed arguments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29139/how-does-solidity-tightly-packed-arguments-work-in-sha256)